# Material UI button label colour won't change after changing disabled state

Tags: safari, material-ui

After changing programmatically the "disabled" parameter of Material UI button the labels' color won't change on Safari. (It works for Chrome).

CodeSandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-forked-8ly0d

Comment: this appears to be good case for [opening an issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues)

Comment: I tried to open an issue and found out that in the "next" version of material/core package (they won't sandboxes to work with this version) it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26251
you need to add a prop `key` to your `<Button>` component to force it to re-render:

```
<Button key={`${disabled}`} disabled={disabled} />
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you have multiple buttons

Comment: In this case you have to provide unique key attribute for each button. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes I tried but it replicate buttons. One was disabled and one was enabled.